# Add new single-character variables to list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr

I need to merge a long list of dataframes in R, and I'd like to create an identifier variable for each using  `purrr::map` and `dplyr::mutate`. The result will be a new variable for each dataframe that is unique and a single string.

Here is a reprex of the error I'm getting. How can I fix this?

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 <- mtcars %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    select(1:3)

df_2 <- mtcars %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    select(4:6)

df_ls <- list(df_1, df_2)


new_vary <- c('first dataframe', 'second dataframe')


map2(df_ls, new_vary, function(x, y){
    x %>% 
        mutate(new_variable = new_vary)
})
#> Error: Column `new_variable` must be length 32 (the number of rows) or one, not 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use  the `y` if it is anonymous function or `.y` with `~`

```
map2(df_ls, new_vary, ~ .x %>% 
                               mutate(new_variable = .y))
```

---

In `base R`, it is done with `Map`

```
Map(cbind, df_ls, new_variable = new_vary)
```

---

NOTE: 'new_vary' is a vector with two elements.  With `map2`, it is looping through teach element of the `list` ('df_ls') along with the corresponding element of 'new_vary'.  Calling the 'new_vary' inside the `mutate` will get the whole `vector` instead of the element inside the `vector`